# what's the operator for `!!`?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In the [controller_helpers.ex](https://github.com/hexpm/hexpm/blob/main/lib/hexpm_web/controllers/controller_helpers.ex) of hexpm project. The `logged_in?` function use `!!`. What's the meaning of this operation?

```
  def logged_in?(conn) do
    !!conn.assigns[:current_user]
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the programming language in question is Elixir, the double exclamation mark (!!) has the following meaning:

> It enforces a boolean value

- `!` means not
- `!!` means not not forcing true or false

It is a double application of a unary operator.

[Documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/operators.html)

Comment: Just a small addition: here is the link to the [Kernel.!/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#!/1) macro itself.

Comment: I personally prefer the cleaner intent: `not !foo`.

Comment: Fun fact that I just discovered: Elixir actually optimizes `!!` as one single `case` expression: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/main/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L1867

Answer (score 1):

First we take a look at ! `operator`

Non-strict not (`!`) works same as `not` operator but does not expect the argument to be a Boolean.

So if we have a variable `life = 43` then `!life` will give false. And if we have `life = nil` then `!life` will give true. This operator just converts the given value to an inverted boolean value.

And now `!!`

Actually `!!` is not an operator it's just that the `!` operator is used twice.
By adding another `!` we are just inverting the result of the first `!` operator.

```
life = 42
    
!life  // Inverted Boolean (false)
!!life // Non-inverted Boolean (true)

end = nil

!end  // Inverted Boolean (true)
!!end // Non-inverted Boolean (false)
```